# What is the use case of Automatic protection ring , ERPS, ECFM, UP MEPs or Down MEPs in ISP now?

Tags: switch, router

What is the need for ISP now - ring protection link protocol, ECFM, UP MEPS, DOWN MEPS - basically L2 protocols? Or ISP needs only MPLS, L3, VPLS, VPWS - L3 protocols only now. I am asking this question is do we need to know these L2 protocols and are they being used by the industry or ISP? Does with L3 protocol there is no need to worry about ECFM,RPL, or MEF-8 protocols.

Comment: Why do you think ISPs only need MPLS L2 and L3 VPNs?

Comment: I mean does ISP need L2 protocols anymore or not? Are these ECFM, UP MEPs and Down MEPs obsolete?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a gap in your knowledge perhaps because your question is not 100% clear to me, it doesn't make perfect sense.

> What is the need for ISP now - ring protection link protocol, ECFM, UP MEPS, DOWN MEPS - basically L2 protocols?

Ethernet CFM (Connectivity Fault Management) is used by ISPs with Metro Ethernet Networks a.k.a "Met-Nets" or "MANs" (Metropolitan Area Networks that have a continuous Ethernet broadcast domain across the backbone rather that layer 3 between hops). Ethernet CFM and OAM are commonly deployed hand-in-hand in Metro Ethernet Provider or Carrier Ethernet Provider networks to provide service performance statistics and fault identification at the data plane level, to get the same view of the network as the customer.

> Or ISP needs only MPLS, L3, VPLS, VPWS - L3 protocols only now. I am asking this question is do we need to know these L2 protocols and are they being used by the industry or ISP? Does with L3 protocol there is no need to worry about ECFM,RPL, or MEF-8 protocols.

Yes ISPs are using those layer 2 protocols as I described above. MPLS layer 3 VPNs and layer 2 VPNs are overlay services that ISPs can provide across their network. These are services provided to their end customers. Even though the end customers maybe taking an IPVPN service at layer 3 (such as an MPLS L3 VPN for example) the underlying provider backbone may have some layer 2 sections using CFM and OAM to provide monitoring, measuring, fault identification etc.

So hopefully it is clear to you now that running CFM and OAM protocols is independent of whether the customer is taking a L2 VPN or L3 VPN service from the ISP. If the customer is taking a layer 2 VPN service then the service provider can extend their CFM and OAM configuration to include that customers' service (they can include the customers interfaces in MEPs) but if they are taking a layer 3 service over a layer 2 backbone, then perhaps just the backbone is covered by the ISPs CFM/OAM configuration.